# Display a tweet using its id

Tags: html, node.js, twitter

Can I display a tweet using its id ?

for example : 
From the id `876126300649525249` I would like to show the real tweet on my website.

Is it possible ?

Comment: You want to display tweet or you want to create a link to the tweet ?

Comment: I want the user to see a tweet on my website. But I want to show him the tweet using the id of the tweet.

Answer (score 2):

You can display tweets, Using these attributes

```
obj.text, for the text of tweet
obj.created_at, for the date the tweet was made
obj.id_str , for the id of the tweet
```

in order to create a link to the tweet it self, you need to use the str_id attribute like this
https://twitter.com/statuses/ + str_id

e.g. 
https://twitter.com/statuses//876126300649525249

here is a loop that i used on the tweets object after parsing the JSON

```
 for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
        var tweet_text =  obj[i].text;
        var tweet_date = obj[i].user.created_at;
        var tweet_link = "https://twitter.com/statuses/" + obj[i].id_str;       
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

did you check the twitter's API ?

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/id , this may help you .

You can find the  twitter api's here https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Regards

Comment: Yes, of course ! It returns a json... But I want the user to see the tweet with a nice design (the design of a tweet)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [oEmbed API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed) to retrieve a Tweet in embeddable HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

I did it !
To print a tweet you will need the screen name and the id of the tweet.

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en">
<a href="https://twitter.com/put the screen name here/status/put the tweet's id
here"></a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Thaynk you all for your responses.